# Is DEFINE_MUTEX a function or a macro?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, udev

I'm trying to get a grasp on C and module development,
(following the excellent example at http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/08/writing-linux-device-driver-for-kernels.html )

Now, what is DEFINE_MUTEX? A function? A macro?

```
DEFINE_MUTEX(parrot_device_mutex);
```

If a function, what's the principle on UC-function names?

(If any more guides on udev-development, please hint.)

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=DEFINE_MUTEX pretty much answers it (first hit on Google search).

Comment: A better way to answer this question is to first look in the relevant header file and look for `DEFINE_MUTEX`. There is often documentation there explaining its purposes. This is just general advice for any macro or function or any symbol in general defined from a header file. And yes, ALL_UPPERCASE is typically used for macros and/or compile-time constants, but this is just a popular convention, not a rule

Comment: @dvnrrs, thanks, but page you're refeering to says both "Defined as a preprocessor macro" AND "Defined as a function prototype...". How should one read that from a noob perspective?

Comment: LXR's using the wrong terminology (it should be "declared as a function prototype" rather than "defined"), and it is wrong in its parse heuristics (since it is not in fact a function at all).

Comment: It shows it in `mutex.h` as a macro. All the other listings are `.c` files. Anyway my point is this kind of thing is easily searchable (not just on LXR).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a MACRO

```
#define DEFINE_MUTEX(mutexname) struct mutex mutexname = __MUTEX_INITIALIZER(mutexname)
```

Refer to Linux/include/linux/mutex.h